# When console log in the fuction getting old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have "operators" state in context and when the app starts the data is fetched and the state is updated. I pass this data to the function and select the component. I'm getting exact data in select component but if I console log in the function, the old value (empty array) returns.

Function where i console log:

```
const onCallStart = callDetails => {
    console.log('operators', operators)
}
```

Where I use data in the select component

```
 <ProSelect
   placeholder="İstifadəçini seçin"
   data={operators}
   value={selectedOperator}
   onChange={id => setSelectedOperator(id)}
 />
```

Update:
I found the reason. I'm passing the function to the jssip listener. It is saving initial value and using it. I extracted it from the listener and calling it when the button is pressed. The problem is fixed.

Comment: Can you please create and share the link to codesandbox

Comment: @ziishaned it's ***always preferable*** to have the code in the question as a [runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Moreover, it's ***always required*** that all relevant code for the question is *in* the question, not behind an off-site link. If the link changes or is taken down, then we lose a crucial part of the question and future visitors will lose out. So, please don't recommend that code is put on off-site. Links should be supplementary only.

Answer (score 0):

### **This is expected behaviour since [React is updating state in a batch](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)**

Which mean that the state only gets an update after an eventHandler/function is finished

If you want to log the latest state, use an `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('operators', operators)
}, [operators]);
```

**You should not worry about that since your app still working as expected**

Comment: The state updating only once. (I'm listening to the state with the useEffect hook.) But in the function, the initial value returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due that you log your variable "operators" before the fetch data request is finish.
Your template show the data because it get update a soon the operator variable change (due to reactivity binding on this variable).
In order to log the variable with data, you have to wait until the request is finish. For that either you use async/await or log in the then/catch .

Comment: This function is called when it got a phone call and when the call is answered the modal is opened. It shows an empty array in the console log but in the select component of the modal, I'm getting exact data.